# torch Conv1d GPU memory spikes during backward prop. on smaller inputs

Tags: python, memory, pytorch, conv1d

*(Short reproducible code below.)*

A **very** bizarre behavior while using torch.Conv1d:
when feeding a smaller input (below some threshold), the GPU memory usage spikes sharply during backward - an order of magnitude or more.

We hypothesize that this has to do with torch/cuda using different algorithms for the convolution depending on dimensions and available memory; problem is, that this results very undesired OOM errors on runtime.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
%load_ext pytorch_memlab

base_ch = 512
d_pos = 64


def print_gpu_mem_usage(prefix=""):
    print(f"{prefix}Peak memory: {torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated() / 1024 ** 3:.2f} GB"
          f" | {torch.cuda.max_memory_reserved() / 1024 ** 3:.2f} GB"
          f" (Current: {torch.cuda.memory_allocated() / 1024 ** 3:.2f} GB"
          f" | {torch.cuda.memory_reserved() / 1024 ** 3:.2f} GB)")


def isolated_conv(v):
    samp_conv = nn.Conv1d(base_ch + d_pos, 2 * base_ch, kernel_size=1, padding='valid').cuda()
    mn = samp_conv(v).mean()
    mn.backward()
```

`%mlrun -f isolated_conv isolated_conv(torch.rand(5000, base_ch+d_pos, 11).cuda())`

| :active_bytes: | :reserved_bytes: | :line: | :code: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all | all |  |  |
| ----peak---- | -----peak----- | ---- | ---- |
| 108.00M | 108.00 | 6 | def isolated_conv(v): |
| 328.00M | 346.00M | 7 | mn = nn.Conv1d(.....) |
| 542.00M | 562.00M | 8 | mn.backward() |

however, switch n samples from 5000 to 4000 and it explodes:

`%mlrun -f isolated_conv isolated_conv(torch.rand(4000, base_ch+d_pos, 11).cuda())`

| :active_bytes: | :reserved_bytes: | :line: | :code: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all | all |  |  |
| ----peak---- | -----peak----- | ---- | ---- |
| 86.00M | 86.00 | 6 | def isolated_conv(v): |
| 260.00M | 280.00M | 7 | mn = nn.Conv1d(.....) |
| 8.07G | 8.25G | 8 | mn.backward() |

Same happens also if I test the two on opposite order.

This runs on a docker, so if you can't reproduce with the following versions I can share a Dockerfile.

edit/add-it: I read now about `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True`
which slightly changes this behavior, still the problem occurs when I go down to 3000 samples.

- torch == 2.0.1
- pytorch-memlab == 0.3.0
- Nvidia 2080Ti
- Driver Version: 525.105.17
- CUDA Version: 12.0

Comment: A couple of suggestions:

If the GPU memory is fragmented, it might cause unexpected memory spikes. You can reset the GPU memory cache using: 

```torch.cuda.empty_cache()```

PyTorch's CuDNN backend has a "benchmark" mode where it runs multiple algorithms and selects the best one based on the performance. It can be turned on using:
```torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True```

Comment: Thank you. These are all good suggestions!! Which I've tried, and haven't solved the problem... tried to empty_cache, it doesn't change this behavior. also tried the cudnn.benchmark as True or False, still I get undesirable results. going to try training with the deterministic flag and see if it doesn't at least crash.